# Enabling GDS Library at Database Level in Neo4j Enterprise Edition - "No procedure with name gds.version registered for this database instance"

Tags: charts, neo4j, graph-theory, enterprise

I am using Neo4j Enterprise Edition 4.4 and I want to utilize the Graph Data Science (GDS) library for advanced graph analytics. I have confirmed that GDS is installed on my Neo4j instance, but when I attempt to call any GDS procedure, such as `gds.version()`, I encounter the error message

> There is no procedure with name gds.version registered for this database instance.

Could anyone please guide me on how to enable the GDS library at the database level in Neo4j Enterprise Edition successfully? Are there any specific configurations or settings that need to be applied to make the GDS procedures accessible within my database instance?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the GDS procedures are not part of your Allowlist. See https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/installation/neo4j-server/ for the concrete settings.

Comment: these are my setting: dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=,apoc.*,bloom.*,gds.* & dbms.security.procedures.allowlist=apoc.coll.*, apoc.load.*,gds.* . Unrestricted property starts with "," is this Ok ?

Comment: Yes these should work. For GDS enterprise you also need to specify the location of your license file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).